# grunt-contrib-copy dies with EPERM operation not permitted "C:\Documents and Settings"

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying to run a simple `grunt` task using `grunt-contrib-copy`, but it dies immediately on reaching the copy task, with this message:

> Running "copy:main" (copy) task
>
> Warning: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Documents and Settings' Use --force to continue
>
> Aborted due to warnings

I am running:

- Windows 7 64-bit (so `C:\Documents and Settings` doesn't exist)
- node 0.10.28 (installed at `C:\nodejs`)
- npm 1.4.9
- grunt-cli 0.1.13
- grunt 0.4.5
- grunt-contrib-copy 0.5.0

I have done a full-text search for "Documents and Settings" on both `C:\nodejs` and my project folder (`C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Programming\myprojectname`, with no spaces or parentheses in there), but nothing matches.

My `copy` task definition is:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [
            {expand: true, cwd: 'src/core', src: '/**', dest: 'src/chrome/'},
            {expand: true, cwd: 'src/core', src: '/**', dest: 'src/firefox/'}
        ]
    }
},
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was the `src: '/**'` properties in the original code.

I changed it to this, and now it works perfectly:

```
copy: {
    main: {
        files: [
            {expand: true, cwd: 'src/core', src: '**/*', dest: 'src/chrome/'},
            {expand: true, cwd: 'src/core', src: '**/*', dest: 'src/firefox/'}
        ]
    }
},
```

The `/**` src property was breaking it, and `**/*` works correctly. I'm pretty new to Grunt, so I didn't realize the former syntax was a problem; I somehow got the impression it would be treated as a relative path.

I searched high and low for an answer to this before posting my question. The Grunt docs have [a good explanation of Grunt's globbing patterns (`*`, `**`, etc.)](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), but it doesn't mention leading slashes being a problem. So, I figured I would leave this up for anyone else who runs into this kind of problem. I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Had a similar issue but was jscs instead of copy.  Your answer saved me quite a bit of time, thanks.